# How to exclude TextField tap while hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Currently, I am hiding the keyboard when the user taps anywhere. I want to exclude 2 `TextField`s tap to avoid the keyboard hide/show effect.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @FocusState var focus:FocusedField?
    @State var name = ""
    @State var email = ""
    @State var phoneNumber = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("Name:",text: $name)
                .focused($focus, equals: .name)
                .onSubmit {
                    focus = .email
                }
            TextField("Email:",text: $email)
                .focused($focus, equals: .email)
                .onSubmit {
                    focus = .phone
                }
            TextField("PhoneNumber:", text: $phoneNumber)
                .focused($focus, equals: .phone)
                .onSubmit {
                    if !name.isEmpty && !email.isEmpty && !phoneNumber.isEmpty {
                        submit()
                    }
                }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if (focus != nil) {
                hideKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }

    private func submit() {
        print("submit")
    }
    
    enum FocusedField: Hashable {
        case name, email, phone
    }
}

extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        print("hideKeyboard")
        let resign = #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder)
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(resign, to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

I want:

1. A stable keyboard for my `TextField`s with no hide and show effects.
2. Tap anywhere to dismiss/hide the keyboard.

Please see the following effects:

[image]

Comment: Which iOS versions do you support?

Comment: iOS version 16.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
public struct TapToHideKeyboardView: View {
    
    public init() {
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.hideKeyboard()
        }) {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.brown)
        }
        .background(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color.clear
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.hideKeyboard()
                }
        )
    }
    
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Use this public struct inside Zstack.

```
var body: some View{
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack {
                TapToHideKeyboardView()
                VStack{
                    TextField("Name:",text:$name)
                        .focused($focus, equals: .name)
                        .onSubmit {
                            focus = .email
                        }
                    TextField("Email:",text:$email)
                        .focused($focus,equals: .email)
                        .onSubmit {
                            focus = .phone
                        }
                    TextField("PhoneNumber:",text:$phoneNumber)
                        .focused($focus, equals: .phone)
                        .onSubmit {
                            if !name.isEmpty && !email.isEmpty && !phoneNumber.isEmpty {
                                submit()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a modifier that defines keyboard dismissal available since iOS 16:

```
func scrollDismissesKeyboard(_ mode: ScrollDismissesKeyboardMode) -> some View
```

You probably want the `immediately` mode.

```
var body: some View{
    List {
        // etc.  
    }
    .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.immediately)
}
```

This does not dismiss the keyboard on tap but on scroll which is the typical iOS behaviour.

Comment: not working. thanks anyway